# making spring/elastic physics in flutter forge or flame

Tags: flutter-animation, flame

I'm a beginner coder working in Android Studio flutter. I'm trying to make a simple android 2d golf game where you hit the ball by dragging back on a paddle with your finger and on release it snaps back and hits the ball (angry birds style) and the ball uses physics from forge or flame.

I've tried this with forge and flame but couldn't find support for it - the closest thing I could find to what I want to do is [physics-simulation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/physics-simulation), but that doesn't seem to work if forge/flame is in the project.

If there are any examples of something like this in a flutter forge or flame project I'd love to see how its done!

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.